# Express JS, req.params command not working when app deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I'm running the basic express server code(given below). I'm trying to get the req.params values through routes.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get("/", function(req, res, next){
    res.send("Timestamp Microservice");
});

app.get("/:unix", function(req, res, next){
    res.send(req.params);
});

app.listen(PORT, function(){
console.log("Server running on: " + PORT + "!");
});
```

on localhost:3000/1234, response is a JSON object

```
{ unix: "1234"}
```

but when I deploy this app to Heroku, it shows

```
Cannot GET/1234
```

Can you tell me whats the issue and how it can be resolved? I just started learning Node and Express and don't know much. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Update:
I have to use     body-parser node module and now the issue is resolved.

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: That doesn't really make sense though, since `body-parser` is not used to populate `req.params`, nor is it used for `GET` requests. Perhaps your initial deployment failed, and after adding `body-parser` and redeploying the new code finally hit the server.

Comment: Well, that makes absolutely no sense.  The problem must have been elsewhere.  There is no request body on `GET` requests at all.